# How can you export all the variables in a file you use source on?

Tags: bash

I have 2 files at the moment that is 1 too many.  I have a file named `../environment` that is included into my service descriptions for systemd.  Then I have a `postactivate` file that virtualenvwrapper will source for me after I activate a VENV.

What I want is to source the `../environment` file from inside the `postactivate` file BUT systemd environment files can't include the word export and the sourced file needs export to do what needs to be done.  Is there any option I can use to export all variables defined in `../environment` so that I don't have to maintain two equivalent sets of variables in two different forms?

Here is an example:

../evironment

```
DB_NAME=foo
```

$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate

```
export DB_NAME=foo
```

And I want:
$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate

```
set -export-all-variables
source ../environment
unset -export-all-variables
```

Ignoring for a moment the pathing issues, is there some option I haven't found in bash to do what I'm asking?

Also vscode doesn't want the export statements either so I'd really like to collapse this down to 1 file

I guess my other option would be something like `eval $(sed s//export / ../environment)`

Comment: `set -a` => https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin

Comment: @glennjackman make it an answer. It is much worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was supplied by @glenn jackman

`set -a` => gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin

So in postactivate you can do:

```
cd what-ever-your-working-directory-is

set -a
source ../environment
set +a
```

And now you have 1 file with all your variables in it that can be included in systemd unit files as well

```
EnvironmentFile=absolute-path-to-the-environment-file
```

And vscode can use the file.  3 birds, one stone, win-win-win

Thanks @glenn jackman

Answer (score 0):

You can use process substitution:

```
source <(sed 's/^/export /' ../environment)
```